# running a console app from wpf -"open file security warning"

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application, command-line-arguments

I am trying to call a windows console application in my wpf app. I am doing this using

```
  public Process process1 = new Process();

  process1.StartInfo.WindowStyle= System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  process1.StartInfo.FileName= System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"myexe.exe"
  process1.StartInfo.Arguments= "myargs";
```

when I build my wpf app in release mode and run on a different computer, I get "open file security warning" prompt, which is not very good to have as I am opening multiple exes and i get that warning prompt box all the time.

Is there a way that this "open file -security message/ prompt box can be disabled?

when I run the wpf app in my local computer on which the code was build, this does not happen. Please can anyone help me on this. I don't want user to keep on answering the prompt all the time whenever the console exes is called. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot or better yet the exact text of the message box?

Comment: Seems like Windows UAC security to me. Try running as Admin account

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt for looking in to this...I can't attach image but it is uploaded as link https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYKYs.png

Comment: If you download anything from an internet location, windows may add a flag to the executable. Look in the file properties for a "Security" entry below "Attributes". See for instance: https://www.howtogeek.com/70012/what-causes-the-file-downloaded-from-the-internet-warning-and-how-can-i-easily-remove-it/

Comment: Thanks grek, but the console which would have this properties is been called from my program from inside, can I change the property there? , beacuse when I tried this, it did work for my external wpf exe, it did not give any prompt but for console called from inside , it does give the same prompt of open file security.